# Oracle Forms Developer Drag display items between canvases

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Could anyone tell me if its possible to drag display items from one canvas to another? For instance I have a drag and drop function on my form that allows the user to drag display items to different areas that will then update the database.

For reasons too long to go into I had to modify the form so that the main form included a stacked canvas (this stacked canvas changes between 9 other stacked canvases). I now need to be able to drag a display item from my main form to this stacked canvas and vice versa.

When you try to drag it from the stacked canvas onto the main form it wont let me drag it from the boundary of the stacked canvas, if I try to drag an object from the main form onto the stacked canvas it disappears behind it.

Is this possible somehow or do I need to go back to the drawing board?

I should probably mention that im using a very old version of forms. Forms 4.5

Comment: And here I thought the Forms 6i that I use was outdated :-)

Comment: It should be helpful if you could describe how you have implemented the drag and drop functionality?

Comment: @DJPeter I am using the drag.pll library

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with that library so I can't help you with the details.

Comment: @DJPeter if you cant halp me with the library or this problem in particular maybe you can sugguest something else that would work? For instance is it possible to create a group of objects(display items) that I could then use on multiple canvases. Rather than create new objects for each canvas. I could probably get it working using that method if 1 set of objects can be used...

Comment: I haven't been working with drag and drop so I have hard to visualize this problem. I'm not aware about any way to create this kind of sets of objects. I think if you need this functionality you need to go back to the drawing board to get ride of the stacked canvas. I'm sorry that I can't help you any more :-|

Comment: @djpeter thanks for the help. I got the form working by using stacked canvases to hold the display items. These canvases can then be dragged around the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way to acomplish this using the drag.pll library I had to re-design my layout without using the individual stacked canvases.